# Ember.js: Getting checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ember.js

How do I get the checkboxes that have been checked, in a case where I iterate over values to create a variable range of checkboxes?

**HBS:**

```
<ul>
{{#each item in model}}
  <li><label>{{input type="checkbox"}} {{item}}</label></li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

**Route:**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  actions: {
    iHaveSelected: function() {
      // Get checked items
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tucoka/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to track if a checkbox is checked you need to bind the [`checked`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/#toc_checkboxes) attribute to a property on a controller.
In the below example the checkbox would be bound to the `isChecked` property.

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked}}
```

In your case you were looping over an array, the way to do it would be to set an [`itemController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_itemController) on the `ArrayController`.
The `itemController` would maintain the `isChecked` state for each item in the `ArrayController`. You would then be able to filter the `ArrayController` by which items are checked.

I created a bin with an example here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vutezo/1/edit

Comment: Thank you, that looks great. Can I nest this within another view?

Comment: i'm not sure exactly what you mean but you should be able to put a nest checkbox where in any view

Comment: Say the colors is a property on the model (or controller), I suppose I would have to isolate the colors property to be handled by an ArrayController? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zujobe/1/edit